# Trying to understand XML Pull Parser in Android - Java

Tags: java, android, xml

I was following a tutorial for reading RSS feeds using XML. Please know that I am a very visual learner and the person teaching tried to explain it in words but sadly I didn't understand :(. So I'm hoping someone can explain.

```
 StringBuilder tempBuffer = new StringBuilder();

        try{
            URL xmlUrl = new URL(URLPath);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) xmlUrl.openConnection();
            int response = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();
            Log.d("Downloaded Data", " Response Code:" + response);

            InputStream is = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);

            int charRead;
            char[] buffer = new char[500];

            while(true){

                charRead = isr.read(buffer);

                if(charRead <= 0){
                    break;
                }


                tempBuffer.append(String.copyValueOf(buffer, 0, charRead));

            }
            return tempBuffer.toString();
```

Now the thing I want to try to understand  is the char[] buffer = new char[500].  What does it mean when we do charRead = isr.read(buffer), in regard to reading the stream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to explain it as a visual example.

Imagine an `InputStream` as a conveyor belt coming out of a hole in the wall (the network). There is a series of `char`s on the conveyor belt, but you need to bring them to you before you can take them off the conveyor belt and process them into your bucket (`buffer`, which can only hold 500 `char`). When you call `isr.read(buffer)`, the conveyor belt operator is told to start the conveyor belt. The conveyor belt will start to roll, dumping the `char` objects into the bucket (`buffer`). This will continue until either

A. The conveyor belt dumps `500` `chars` into the bucket (`buffer`), or

B. The conveyor belt runs out of `chars` coming out of the hole in the wall (network).

The line of code:

```
if(charRead <= 0){
    break;
}
```

Tells the conveyor belt that if NOTHING came out of the hole in the wall when the button was pressed to stop pressing the button and exit the loop.

The line of code:

```
tempBuffer.append(String.copyValueOf(buffer, 0, charRead));
```

tells the conveyor belt operator to stop what he's doing (after the conveyor belt stopped moving because either 500 `chars` got dumped into the bucket or the conveyor belt ran out of `chars`) and take everything that's in the bucket (`buffer`), and take out `charRead` amount of `chars`. Basically, this is everything that's in the bucket, because we know that `charRead` is how many `chars` came off the conveyor belt and went into the bucket, so if we take `charRead` `chars` from the bucket, we know that we got all of them. These are appended onto the `StringBuilder`, and the loop starts over again!

Answer (score 0):

It reads up to 500 bytes (the length of the buffer) from the stream and puts it in buffer.  charRead is the number of characters it actually read-  somewhere from 0 to 500, depending on how much data was waiting.  charRead can also be less than 0 in case of an error.

Comment: OKay. So from what you said, all the code is doing is just taking 500 characters from the stream and putting it into the buffer array then assigning that to charRead and keep doing that until the number of characters read is zero, meaning the stream is finished? If this is the case, when the loop is complete and then restarts wouldn't the buffer already be populated? I think im confused about the purpose of the buffer.

Comment: The buffer holds the results of the last read.  So you're reading in 500 bytes, processing them, then reading in the next 500, processing them, until the stream is done.  So yes, at the top of the loop the buffer variable is already populated, but its populated with data you've already used and don't mind overwriting.  The reason you don't allocate a new buffer is efficiency-  this loop will be iterating quickly, and allocations can be slow.